# Can I include complete Python scripts from GitHub to a Django application?

Tags: python, django

I have a question before I get started in a whole project...

I'm in a team of 6 people, and I'm the only one using Python. I only use scripts already written, I just put in the arguments and that's it (scripts like Sherlock : https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock or Twint : https://github.com/twintproject/twint

By the time, I learned a bit about coding in Python but really, it remains basic stuff.

Now, my colleagues would like to use these applications too, and I thought about using Django, set up a web server, importing those scripts in the server, and giving the possibility to my colleagues to enter the args in a user-friendly way (some really don't know a thing about programmation)

Is that possible with Django? If yes, will it be complicated?  (I never used Django before and will follow courses, don't have a deadline)

If no, do you guys know of any alternatives that I could use?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Yes it can be done, Django is python so you can import and use any other python function inside a Django project. And no, this question does not belong on SO (ask for a recommendation, tutorial or book is off-topic as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Sorry about asking for recommendation, didn't know about that rule. Gonna edit the post

Comment: Django seems a bit of overkill IMHO, have you considered Flask or Hug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, before starting, go through this tutorial from Django:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

And, to answer your question, if I understood it properly, you want to configure your scripts with the Django environment.

To answer that, yes you can run your Python application using Django, Django itself uses Python, and also without many complications, but for that, you should have basic understanding of, how Django works, and also about Django views. Go through them, and come back if you have further impedance.